# Installing a new version of python3 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, operating-system

I had python 3.8.10 installed on my pc (with Windows 11 Home). I wanted python 3.10, so I download it from the official site and I installed it, but running `python3 --version` in the prompt i continued to get `python 3.8.10`. So I unistalled python 3.8 using the control panel programs and features, but now I continue to get `python 3.8.10` when I run `python3 --version` in the prompt. How can I fix this?
I found online that I need to change the environment variable "path" using the window advanced system settings, but there is nothing related to Python there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install update-alternatives for python versions. You must use exact versions.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8.10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10
```

Then use this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

You should get a result like these:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

You can select your new version from here. For confirmation:

```
python3 --version
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just run:

```bash
python3.10 --version  # or everything you want to do with python 3.10
```